# How to show negative and positive values in a graphic for data visualisation

Tags: info-visualisation, data

I am preparing a proof of concept for a user account dashboard to show positive and negative values within a graph of some sort.

My current solution is to use a pie chart with positive and negative values. I'm wondering if there are any other solutions better for the user?
[image]

Comment: You should define "better for the user". Who are those users and what do they do with the data?

Answer (score 2):

it seems that you want people to be aware of the range of *divergence*.

A problem with pie charts in general is that users have a difficult time comparing values as part of circular shape. They also don't display divergence within a set.

**Visualizing a range**

Try using a Span Bar Chart if you want to show the range of both values.

[image]

If you have more than one pair of these values, you can stack them.

Comment: yes this was also one of my raw concepts. and there are more so it would be stacked.